# Google Scripts: Copy Paste data between two files with criteria on columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to copy paste between two google spreadsheets in google scripts. I was able to find a way to copy between two files (using references by links in script) but not able to do it with multiple criteria on columns. I wanted to avoid doing that via filtering in file, so maybe virtual table.

In summary: two google sheets files, one master, one target. From linked master file, I want to set criteria on multiple columns and the "filtered" data to pasted as values to linked target. Data is too big and changing too frequently to use ‘importrange’ (used it before... looking for improvements).

I just started my journey with google scripts so would appreciate some guidance from You!!

thank you!

Comment: You can transfer data from one spreadsheet to another via setValues() or you could copy the entire sheet to another spreadsheet and then copyTo between between sheets and delete the temporary sheet.

Comment: rather looking for a way to set a criteria on multiple columns to take necessary data from source to target

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function myfunc() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const ssr = 2;//data start row
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');
  const tsh = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let oA=ssh.getRange(ssr,1,ssh.getLastRow() - ssr + 1,ssh.getLastColumn()).getValues().map(r=>{if(r[0]=='Criteria 1' &&  r[1]=='Criteria 2' ) {return r;}}).filter(r=>r[0] != '');
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```